# TCPListener C# capturar los valores recibidos por el mismo.

Tags: c#, telnet

Necesito realizar una aplicación que guarde el log de un Telnet realizado a ip 10.123.12.123, por poner un ejemplo, con un puerto 1234 por ejemplo también.

El problema es que mirando ejemplos no consigo entender como funciona la clase socket, no sé si es que la estoy creando mal o no.

La aplicación consta simplemente de un botón, cuando lo pulsas inicia la conexión y empieza a guardar el log en un fichero de texto/BBDD, aún no sé como lo haré.

He visto códigos y ejemplos pero no consigo entender que es lo que va pasando en el programa, no sé si alguien podría realizar un ejemplo sencillo de un listener que guarde información sobre una conexión telnet.

Gracias por adelantado.

Esto es lo que me devuelve TELNET y necesito añadir esos valores con fechas y demás en una BBDD

[image: Captura Telnet, conectando al servidor]

La cosa es, yo escribo en CMD: `Telnet 10.123.12.123 1234` una vez entra al servidor hago login con `login user password` y una vez dentro lanzo el comando `queueinfo` para que me devuelva los datos de las colas que hay en el momento, lo que necesito exactamente es que en mi programa queden registrados los valores que me devuelve para guardarlos en una base de datos con un `datetime.now` o algún equivalente del mismo.

[image: Consola de comandos, telnet, abierto desde CMD]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ColasTelnet
{
    class TelnetServer
    {

        public static void conectar()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;


            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("10.123.12.123");

            server = new TcpListener(ip, 1234);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            server.Start();

            byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;


            while (true)
            {

                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                data = null;

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


                int i;

                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    MessageBox.Show("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    MessageBox.Show("Sent: {0}", data);
                }
            }

        }





    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Aritz. Si has intentado algo, pégalo aquí para que veamos que es lo que tienes mal y entendamos un poco mejor la pregunta. `Telnet` es un protocolo para manejar remotamente otra maquina, no se que tiene que ver con crear un socket.

Comment: Copio todo lo que tengo, espero que así esté mejor.

Comment: Lo siento,pero sigo sin entender que es lo que quieres conseguir, por qué insistes hablando de Telnet?.Describe exactamente tu situación (por ejemplo,quieres conectar dos equipos y comunicarte entre ellos?)

Comment: Siento si no consigo explicarme, es algo que nunca me habían pedido hacer. 

La cosa es, yo mediante telnet puedo establecer conexión con otro servidor, hago login en el mismo, con login user password, y una vez hecho el login el servidor me envía información sobre llamadas entrantes, cuando ahí hay un 1, es que hay una llamada en espera. 

Lo que necesito es que ese 1 quede registrado a la hora que cada vez que me mande un valor, este valor quede registrado en una base de datos junto a la fecha recibida. 

Espero haberme explicado así.

Comment: O sea, que nada más loguearte en el otro equipo (seguro que por telnet?), éste responde con una información antes de mostrar el prompt del sistema?

Comment: Una vez logueado hago un queueinfo y este me empieza a mandar valores, más bien, se me olvidó el detalle. Es por telnet. Es decir, la lista de comandos que yo uso es, una vez abierto cmd: [telnet 10.123.12.123 1234 >> login user password >> queueinfo ]

Comment: Vale, ya empiezo a entender. Una vez en el prompt del sistema, debes ejecutar un comando (queueinfo) para que comience a sacar la información por consola para poder almacenarla. Tal vez debes editar tu pregunta y añadir toda esta información para que esté mas clara.

Comment: Voy a reescribirla con capturas para que quede todo más claro, a ver si consigo encontrar una solución, pues el encargado del proyecto quiere que se haga así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, yo te recomendaría que utilizaras alguna de las librerías disponibles para telnet en .Net. Pero te doy una idea básica de como puedes conectarte y obtener los datos.

Lo que necesitas es usar la clase `TcpClient`,no `TcpListener`. El proceso básicamente es conectarte al servidor, esperar a que telnet te vaya pidiendo los datos necesarios para loguearte y una vez lo estés, enviar el comando. Mas o menos,asi:

```
byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
String data = null;
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("10.123.12.123");
TcpClient cliente = new TcpClient();
cliente.Connect(ip, 1234);

while (true)
{
    NetworkStream stream = cliente.GetStream();
    int i;

    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
        Console.WriteLine("Recibido: {0}", data);

        data = data.ToUpper();

        byte[] msg;
        if (data.Contains("USERNAME:")) //Tienes que asegurarte que el texto que manda el servidor es igual que esto
        {
            //enviamos el nombre de usuario
            msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tuUsuario" + Environment.NewLine);
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        }

        if (data.Contains("PASSWORD:"))
        {
            //enviamos la contraseña
            msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tuContraseña" + Environment.NewLine);
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        }

        if (data.Contains("$")) //aqui debes poner el simbolo de sistema que 
        {
            msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("queueinfo" + Environment.NewLine);
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        }

    }
}
```

Esto es un ejemplo para un telnet normal. Si es proceso para el tuyo es diferente, simplemente debes adaptar que te envia el servidor y que debes contestarle tu a continuación. Simplemente en la consola vas viendo si te da algun error o el proceso va funcionando.

Comment: Efectivamente @AritzBello. Como te digo al final, debes adaptarlo a tu caso, pero básicamente es el mismo proceso que haces manualmente: esperar algo del servidor y enviar algo en respuesta

Comment: Siento si parece una pregunta estúpida, pero, entonces, el if(data.contains("Password... como el Username, en mi caso sobrarían, ya que es el segundo comando que tengo que enviar, y a parte de eso, cuando pones //Aquí debes de poner el simbolo de sístema que... ¿Que qué?

Comment: @AritzBello en un telnet normal, primero se solicita el usuario y despues el password. Si en tu caso no es asi, pues efectivamente sobra, tendras que enviar el comando login user password.En cuanto al simbolo, en telnet una vez logueado aparece el simbolo de sistema para esperar los comandos. En tu caso, deberás probablemente esperar a algo como `LOGINOK` en lugar de `$`

Comment: Entiendo, y ya para terminar, como puedo capturar los mensajes que me devuelve telnet? es decir, la cola, las líneas, sería algo tipo 'if (data.Contains("queueinfo")){  getlinea  //o el metodo equivalente. }'  No sé si me explico. Es decir, ahora mismo, si yo ejecuto el programa, efectivamente si conecto con el servidor, pero el mismo no me devuelve nada. Para lanzar el comando es "String"+enviroment... eso?

Comment: Si, sería `if (data.contains("queueinfo")){//procesar la línea}`. Debes tener en consideración la posibilidad de que en `data` haya mas de una línea, eso dependerá de varios factores.Y si, para los comandos es igual que si los tecleases, enviando comando + enter (`Environment.Newline`)

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo, no consigo encontrar el if para hacer el login, pero ya me buscaré la vida. Gracias.